# Auto generate action in controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to use VS more efficiently, and I was looking for a way to generate a method automatically. For example, I know if you type `foreach` then press `TAB` twice it generates the skeleton code, so if I had a method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CloseTicket()
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Is there a way of generating the 'skeleton code' so I don't have to manually type it out. I looked into [method stubs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a7hkh29%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) but they don't seem to apply to this.

Comment: there's a built in snippet: type `mvcaction4` and hit tab to help you stub an action.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. If you want to put that as an answer I'll tick you, thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are built-in snippets in Visual Studio to help with this:

```
mvcaction4
```

inserts:

```
public ActionResult Action()
{
    return View();
}
```

And

```
mvcpostaction4
```

Inserts

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks..A small help from my side- Use short cut CTRL+K, CTRL+X to insert snippets in visual studio.This link gives more info : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c5cc9b(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: technically it's `Ctrl + K, X`, but that one works too

Comment: I too thought so but just followed MSDN way as mentioned in url.

Comment: @DLeh its not working for me in **VS 2017 Community** edition. I am getting [this](http://prntscr.com/get90y)

Answer (score 2):

If it is not there you can create a code snippet. Just put in in the right folder and VS will use it.

For VS2013 put it in folder:

\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets

See here how to create a code snippet
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx